# UndefinedMethodException in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1606

Tags: php, symfony

I'm somewhat lost what I've done here.  My app was functioning for a while, and at some point I changed something that caused this error. I've cleared my dev cache. At some point I wonder if I updated my composer and caused something because I wasn't even touching the php side of my app when I broke it.

Here's the full error:

```
UndefinedMethodException in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1606:
Attempted to call an undefined method named "AddAthlete" of class "FOS\RestBundle\Util\FormatNegotiator".
```

That particular function looks like this:

```
protected function getFosRest_ExceptionFormatNegotiatorService()
{
    $this->services['fos_rest.exception_format_negotiator'] = $instance = new \FOS\RestBundle\Util\FormatNegotiator();

    $instance->AddAthlete($this->get('fos_rest.request_matcher.0dfc4cce134bee15f08405cb5cea4845b13ff7d8c8f779004218432a2c552bd0cd9f9d27'), array('priorities' => array(0 => 'html', 1 => 'json', 2 => 'xml'), 'fallback_format' => NULL, 'prefer_extension' => '2.0', 'methods' => NULL, 'stop' => false));

    return $instance;
}
```

I'm not particularly familiar with how this gets generated.  Could someone help? If needed, here's [a link](https://github.com/RichHatch/athletes/tree/master/src/AppBundle) to my bundle on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I must have had some composer issues because when I pulled the repo down to my other machine, it worked fine (with the exception of new bugs, yay!)